# Java practice programming prob

Tags: java

I was solving this problem on HackerRank
you can see the question here
https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/programming-jam-2-0/challenges/math-practice

> You have devised a strategy that helps your kid practice his mathematics. First, you pick a positive integer N. Then you tell your kid to starts naming N, 3 × N, 5 × N, 7 x N and so on.
>
> Whenever he names a number, he thinks about all of the digits in that number. He keeps track of which digits (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9) he has seen at least once so far as part of any number he has named. Once he has seen each of the ten digits at least once, he is allowed to go play

and also my code but when I submit it gives me (no response on stdout)
I revised the code many times and I don't know where is the mistake
Please can anyone help

```
package contest;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
*
* @author Mohamed
*/
public class Solution 
{
   public static void main(String [] s){
      Scanner In = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number = In.nextInt();
    int counter = 1;
    int length;
    int oneDigit;
    int newNumber;
    int index;
    boolean condition = true;
    int [] arr = new int[10];
    
    ArrayList<String> theList = new ArrayList<>();
    
    while(condition = true){
        length = (int)(Math.log10(number) + 1);
        newNumber = number;
        while(length > 0)
        {
           oneDigit = newNumber % 10;
           newNumber = newNumber / 10;
        
           if(arr[0] != oneDigit && arr[1] != oneDigit && arr[2] != oneDigit       && 
              arr[3] != oneDigit && arr[4] != oneDigit && arr[5] != oneDigit &&
              arr[6] != oneDigit && arr[7] != oneDigit && arr[8] != oneDigit &&
              arr[9] != oneDigit)
           {
              String num = String.valueOf(oneDigit);
              theList.add(num);
              index = theList.lastIndexOf(num);
              arr[index] = oneDigit;
           }
           if(newNumber == 0){
               length = 0;
           }
           else{
              length = (int)(Math.log10(newNumber) + 1);
           }
        } 
        counter = counter + 2;
        if(arr[9] != 0)
        {
             System.out.println(number);
             condition = false;
        }
        number = number * counter;
        }
      }
  }
```

Comment: `while(condition = true)` will loop forever, because you're assigning `true` to the variable, and that is also the result of the expression. You might have meant `while(condition == true)`, but you shouldn't write that either, but instead write `while(condition)`.

Comment: IMO, Best way to answer HackerRank is to not write the code completely in HackerRank

Comment: @cricket_007 Agreed. Always write and test your code locally using an IDE. In this case, the IDE would have told you about the `while(condition = true)` problem.

Comment: Where is your logic for printing `NO PLAY`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sets to fid out the digits seen. Sets do not allow duplicate

Your code in should look like this :

```
Scanner In = new Scanner(System.in);
int number = In.nextInt();
int index = 1;
int newNum;
String message = "";
Set<Integer> numbersSeen = new HashSet<Integer>();

while(true)
{
    newNum = number*index;
    message += "N ="+number*index+".  Now he has seen the digits ";
    while(newNum > 0) {
        numbersSeen.add(newNum % 10);
        newNum /= 10;
    }
    for(Integer seenNum : numbersSeen) {
        message += seenNum +", ";
    }
    System.out.println(message.substring(0,message.length()-2));
    message = "";
    index +=2;
    if(numbersSeen.size() == 10) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

debug it locally! it just has single `println`, based on some condition. you will have nothing printed if this condition is not met.

Also, I would advise some refactoring to make code more understandable.

- rename condition variable to something meaningful. like isArray9Zero. Why algorithm stops only when `arr[9] != 0` ?
- make named function out of long i`f(arr[0] != oneDigit`. What is being checked there?